# clj-http works locally but not inside my apex.run managed Lambda function

Tags: java, apache, lambda, clojure, aws-lambda

I can successfully use `clj-http` locally but I get no response or error message when running inside lambda. The suspect functions are below.

```
(ns org.get_location.lambsay
    (:gen-class :implements [com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler])
    (:require [cheshire.core :as json]
            ;   [cheshire.core :refer [generate-string]] ; could probably include parse-stream here and get rid of above line
              [clojure.java.io :as io]
              [clojure.string :as str]
              [clj-http.client :as client]
              [org.httpkit.client :as http])
    (:import (com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime Context)))

(defn locations
    []
    (println "BBB")
    (:body (client/get "https://www.example.com/resource" {:as :json})))

(defn location
    [lat lng]
    (println "AAA")
    (println (locations))
    (println "CCC")
    (json/generate-string {:statusCode 200 :body (json/generate-string {:hi {:deeper "deepest!" :lat lat :lng lng}})}))

(defn -handleRequest
    [this input-stream output-stream context]
    (let [handle (io/writer output-stream)
          is (json/parse-stream (io/reader input-stream))
          query-string-parameters (get is "queryStringParameters")
          lat (bigdec (get query-string-parameters "lat"))
          lng (bigdec (get query-string-parameters "lng"))
          response (location lat lng)]
        (println response)
        (.write handle response)
        (.flush handle)))
```

My main difficulty is that I'm getting no errors or logs at all after printing `BBB`. The function just appears to stop and never continue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share more code? And one more thing, you could mix location and locationS names causing unwilling recursion.

Comment: @IvanGrishaev I added all the code. Are you saying the namespaces could get mixed up or that I could have a typo?

Comment: What do you mean by getting no response? Is response body empty? What's the response status? 
You can turn on DEBUG logging - especially apache http client (used by clj-http) logs a lot of stuff at DEBUG level.

Comment: Is the AWS lambda log saying that the job has timed out? Does that mean that the lambda cannot contact the web service you're calling? This might be a VPC config problem, or some other error unrelated to the actual Clojure code you're running.